# Equivalent code for calloc

Tags: c++, c

In the given c code snippet what will be the equivalent code for the line
   `int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), 256);` ?

```
int *getCharCountArray(char *str)
{
   int *count = (int *)calloc(sizeof(int), 256);
   int i;
   for (i = 0; *(str+i);  i++)
      count[*(str+i)]++;
   return count;
}
```

Whether it is possible to do this without using calloc? How we can declare this using malloc and new in c++ ?

Comment: Why would you use `malloc` AND `new`?  They are alternate ways of allocating memory, you don't use them together.

Comment: @BenVoigt +1 and you most CERTAINLY do not `free` memory allocated with `new` !

Comment: I know that malloc and new are different. I want to know how to allocate this piece of code using malloc and also using new.

Comment: @sbala_20 `new` basically lets you skip the `sizeof` step, as the size is inferred automagically. Jerry Coffin's answer shows the difference between new and malloc. Read up on `new` and `delete` as they add extra syntactic sugar for instance for `delete []`-ing an array :)

Comment: "Why would you use malloc AND new? " -- Welcome to English, Ben. If, for instance, someone says they want to know how to write a binary search routine in Java and Perl, they don't mean they want to put statements from both languages into the same program.

Comment: @Jim: I'm choosing to interpret the sentence in a way that makes the question permissible here.  If you want to know how to write binary search in Java, and also how to write binary search in Perl, that's two different questions.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're funny. Anyway, sbala_20's response makes clear what the intent was, but I don't think that constitutes two different questions.

Comment: Just a short note on performance: `calloc` is extremely fast in allocating memory initialized with zero. Although the `malloc+memset` is functionally equivalent, it is slower than calloc and additionally its no real C++ style, but more C-style. However, the `new int[3849731]();` is more the C++ way but is also significantly slower than calloc. Please note, that this takes only effect when allocating huge memory blocks! With only small arrays < 10000000 elements you won't notice much difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`calloc` is basically equivalent to `malloc` followed by `memset` to set all the data to zero bytes:

```
void *like_calloc(size_t size, size_t num) { 
    void *ret = malloc(size * num);

    if (ret)  
        memset(ret, 0, size * num);
    return ret;
}
```

C++ provides a syntax for `new` that lets you do this a little more simply:

```
int *count = new int[256]();
```

Note the parens at the end. Also note, however, that you generally do *not* want to do this in C++ at all -- you'd normally want to write the code something like this:

```
std::vector<int> getCharCountArray(unsigned char const *str) { 
     std::vector<int> count(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()+1);

     for (int i=0; str[i]; i++)
         ++count[str[i]];
     return count;
}
```

This obviously simplifies the code a fair amount, but there's more simplification than may be immediately obvious too. Specifically, this avoids the rest of the code having to track when the returned value is no longer needed, and deleting the memory at that point (but no sooner) as is needed with either the C version or the version using `new` in C++.

Comment: what does this line exactly means?std::vector<int> count(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max());

Comment: @sbala_20 Are you asking what `vector<int>` is?  Or what `numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()` is?

Comment: @Drew Dormann I am asking this - count(std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()) . As far as i understood this is initializing count to a maximum value.this is correct? Do u have any link that where i can learn the keywords like this numeric_limit etc..

Comment: @sbala_20: `vector<whatever>(num)` creates a vector of `num` elements, all of them value initialized (which will be set to zero in the case of `int`).

Comment: @sbala_20: you can find all the C++ standard library functions in [http://en.cppreference.com/w/]

Comment: @JerryCoffin: note that `numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()` is the maximum value for an unsigned char, not the number of possible values, that should be `numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max() - numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min() +1`. You are in fact creating a vector with one less element as required.

Comment: @sbala_20 *"As far as i understood this is initializing count to a maximum value"*. No.  It's initializing `count` to *that specific size*.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Good point (though for an unsigned type, there's no need to get the minimum -- it's always 0).

Comment: i downvoted for the unexplained and confusing way of initalizing to 0.

Answer (score 10):

This will allocate 256 ints, and [value-initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) the array to `0`

This does what `calloc` is doing in your code.

```
int *count = new int[256]();
//                       ^^ value-initialization
```

Comment: Yep, it causes *value-initialization*, which for `int` means filling with `0`.

Comment: I favor this one over malloc+memset as this is more C++ styled

Answer (score 2):

`calloc` is the same as `malloc` followed by `memset`

Comment: calloc and malloc are more or less same but calloc is not there in c++. calloc will initialize variable whereas malloc wiould not initialize variable.

Comment: @sbala_20 - `calloc` is part of the C++ standard library.

Comment: Thanks for that info. But when i prepare for my interview, i read that calloc is not there in c++.

Comment: @sbala_20: Then throw out that prep book and get a better one.  `calloc` is listed in Table 153 "Standard functions".  Or even better, interview for a subject where you have real world experience and don't have to blindly trust some book.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I am a fresher and i am learning now. Now i can correct others when they say there is no calloc in c++. Thanks.